# Is it possible to perform "future" soft delete in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I found that the soft-delete in laravel Eloquent ORM is just replacing the null in deleted_at column by a timestamp. When querying a table with soft delete, is it just checking if the deleted_at is null, or it is really comparing the value with current time?

I am asking to see if I am able to do schedule delete by setting a future time on the deleted_at column.

Comment: The timestamp put within the deleted_at column is simply a timestamp of when it was soft deleted. So overall the query on a soft delete enabled model simply checks to see if the column is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel only checks if `deleted_at` is not `NULL`. `SoftDeletingScope`:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $model = $builder->getModel();

    $builder->whereNull($model->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn());

    $this->extend($builder);
}
```

---

You can change that by creating your own `SoftDeletingScope` and `SoftDeletingTrait` (it's called `SoftDeletes` in Laravel 5).

```
trait MySoftDeletingTrait {
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

    public static function bootSoftDeletingTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new MySoftDeletingScope);
    }
}
```

And

```
class MySoftDeletingScope extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope {
    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $model = $builder->getModel();

        $builder->where($model->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn(), '<=', Carbon::now());

        $this->extend($builder);
    }
}
```

**Note** that to be able to remove the scope (the `remove()` method) you would have to override more of the original scope class. At least also `isSoftDeleteConstraint`, but I'll leave that to you.

Finally you only have to switch out the trait that you use in your models:

```
use MySoftDeletingTrait;
```

Comment: Thanks. That was more than what I expected. All I want to know is just if it is possible and I would prefer adding a column in my table / adding a schedule table in my database instead of messing with the original soft delete class.

Comment: You're welcome. Extending and overriding isn't exactly "messing with the original class" but if you don't feel comfortable with it... sure, create your own column and scope :)