# How can I set future Soft Deleted in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

According to this  Question : [Is it possible to perform "future" soft delete in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693284/is-it-possible-to-perform-future-soft-delete-in-laravel)
Is it can use in laravel 5.6  ? and If It can Where can I create Traits

I try to create Traits in app\Traits\ but when I call in in models It always said Trait 'App\Traits\MySoftDeletingTrait' not found

I created 2 file  in app\Traits
- MySoftDeletingScope.php

```
namespace App\Traits;

class MySoftDeletingScope extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope {
    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $model = $builder->getModel();

        $builder->where($model->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn(), '<=', Carbon::now());

        $this->extend($builder);
    }
}

the 2nd one MySoftDeleteingTrait.php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

trait MySoftDeletingTrait {
    public static function bootSoftDeletingTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new MySoftDeletingScope);
    }
}
```

In Uer php I call

use App\Traits\MySoftDeletingTrait;
use Notifiable, HasRoles, MySoftDeletingTrait;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to doubly specify the traits that you use. Firstly, outside of the class definition at the start of the file as an include:

```
use App\Traits\MySoftDeletingTrait;
```

and then later on inside of the class:

```
use Notifiable, HasRoles, MySoftDeletingTrait;
```

Comment: thnks I can use it now but I get and error withTrashed does not exist. How can i fix this I alredy add extends  extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope

Comment: Have you also set the model you are deleting to use soft-deletion (as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting)
e.g. `class User extends Model { use SoftDeletes;`

Comment: No I use MySoftDeletingTrait instead of SoftDeletes because I override some function, and in MySoftDeletingTrait I alredy use  extend extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope which mean I can use softdelete function too isn't it ?

Comment: Is the database migration correct? Does the User table have a deleted_at column?

Comment: yes i have. nvm thanks for helping I will find wat to do nxt